# PHP Socket Types and TCP Window Size

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, mss

So this is really a two part question with the first leading to the second.

I'm working on a PHP server project and I'm a bit confused with all the different ways I can create a socket.  I've managed to create three sockets each using a new method.  Does anyone know the fundamental difference between these three methods if any?

**Method 1 using 'socket_create'**

```
$Socket1 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
socket_bind($Socket1, $LocalIP, $LocalPort)
socket_connect($Socket1, $DestIP, $DestPort)
//Method 1 Read
socket_read($Socket1)
//Method 1 Write
socket_write($Socket1, $WriteMsg, strlen($WriteMsg))
```

**Method 2 using 'fsockopen'**

```
$Socket2 = fsockopen($Server, $Port)
//Method 2 Read
fgets($Socket2)
//Method 2 Write
fputs($Socket2, $PutMsg, strlen($PutMsg))
```

**Method 3 using 'stream_socket_client'**

```
$Socket3 = stream_socket_client('tcp://'.$DestIP.':'.$DestPort)
//Method 3 Read
stream_socket_recvfrom($Socket3, $RecSize)
//Method 3 Write
stream_socket_sendto($Socket3, $SendMsg)
```

Although I don't understand the difference I was exploring all three options looking for a way to control the TCP Window Size.  I'm trying to push a packet to a client over my LAN that has a data payload of 1460 bytes and after reviewing a packet capture the TCP data portion of my packet is always cut short at 1448 bytes. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the actual amount of data received at a time. TCP is a streaming protocol. It presents a byte-stream API to the application. You just have to be prepared to read and re-read until you have got what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the [socket_set_option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php) command (where options are documented in the [socket_get_option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-option.php) command):

```
$Socket1 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
// send window
socket_set_option($Socket1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, 1460);
```

Just be sure to call it right after `socket_create`. If you need the receive window modified:

```
socket_set_option($Socket1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, 1460);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of that interesting option. After a couple more late nights I've discovered the TCP Maximum Segment Size (MSS) value specifies the maximum amount of TCP data in a single IP datagram that the local system can accept (reassemble). 
The SO_SNDBUF option does define the max send buffer size but this can still be fragmented into multiple packets when sent by the lower level TCP protocol.
As it turns out the Ethernet MSS value is 1460 (1500 - 40 = 1460). There’s a TCP Timestamp option being sent out my TCP socket that’s robbing me of the 12 bytes I was looking for.